# I can access iOS Photo Library without requesting permission

Tags: ios, swift, camera, plist

I am trying to access the photo library for a new app that I am writing. I have an actionSheet that allows the user to choose between their camera and their photo library. When opening the camera, it asks the user for permission but when opening the photo library it does not. Despite this, it still brings the user to their photo library. I specifically referenced it in my info.plist, but there is still no difference. Any help? My code:

```
@IBAction func allowAccessToPhotos(_ sender: Any) {

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Photo Source", message: "Choose a Source", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: What have you added in your Info.plist ?

Comment: @MayurKarmur I have added 'Privacy - Camera Usage Description' and 'Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description'

Comment: This is right keys, but not asking for permission, it's weird.

Comment: @BobSamuels have you installed your app before and given permission if so you might like to check permissions in apps setting

Comment: @BobSamuels What is happening is iOS is saving the permission granted to your app mapped to the bundle ID if the app is deleted this data persists for 24 hours, this avoids re-prompting the user if they reinstall the app (perhaps after mistakingly deleting an app).

This also happens for Push Notification prompts.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger I reinstalled it assuming it would clear any saved permissions. I guess that is where I went wrong. Any solutions besides waiting?

Comment: @BobSamuels try checking for 'NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription' key in your photo library??

Comment: @BobSamuels it will be a hack, change your device timing. and Please confirm if it works.

Comment: change your bundle identifier !

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger permissions persisting for 24 hours seems consistent with what I'm seeing. Is this undocumented behavior? I can't find anywhere that Apple mentions it.

Comment: Yes. It seems undocumented for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per `UIImagePickerController` behaviour, It never gives dialogue to the user for `Photos` access. `UIImagePickerController` only ask for the `Camera` permission.

You have to ask for `Photos` `permission` manually to the user. By using the below code you can ask the user for `Photos` permission.

```
import Photos
    
@IBAction func allowAccessToPhotos(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Photo Source", message: "Choose a Source", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        let photoAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        switch photoAuthorizationStatus {
        case .authorized:
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        case .notDetermined:
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({
                (newStatus) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if newStatus ==  PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
                        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }else{
                        print("User denied")
                    }
                }})
            break
        case .restricted:
            print("restricted")
            break
        case .denied:
            print("denied")
            break
        }}))
    
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
}
```

Please refer [reference.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81619)

## Important Note:

> If you're not asking for `Photos` permission to the user then It will cause rejection by the apple team. It depends on your luck, Sometimes the apple team ignore it and sometimes reject our app.

Comment: You need to wrap ui-code inside the requestAuthorization handler to DispatchQueue.main.asynch {} because Photos framework can call it on arbitrary queue https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrary/1620736-requestauthorization?language=objc

Answer (score 3):

From iOS 11, `UIImagePickerController` is running remotely on a separate process.
So, your app doesn't need the standard privacy authorization for Photos library access, it gets read-only access just for whichever asset(s) the user chooses in the imagePicker.

To add new asset into photo-library you need `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` in your Info.plist - [forum thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81619)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can access photos by PhotosUI library without permission

```
import PhotosUI

var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
    config.selectionLimit = 4
    config.filter = .images
    let vc = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
    vc.delegate = self
    self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

extension UIViewController: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
     
 var images = [UIImage]()
    for image in results {
        if image.itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self)  {
            image.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { (newImage, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    self.images.append(newImage as! UIImage)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Loaded Assest is not a Image")
        }
    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

}